# SSLHandshakeException in jython 2.7.0

Tags: java, exception, sslhandshakeexception, jython-2.7

When I try to execute the following code by using jython stand alone 2.7.0 I get **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem**,

```
import jsonrpclib
url = 'https://userName:Password@host/'
ss = jsonrpclib.Server( url )
result = ss.runCmds( 1, [{ "cmd" : "<command>" }  ] )
print result
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/jython/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 288, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/jython/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 237, in _request
    response = self._run_request(request)
  File "/jython/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 251, in _run_request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/jython/Lib/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/jython/Lib/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/jython/Lib/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 126, in send_content
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 812, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 1204, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/jython/Lib/_socket.py", line 357, in handle_exception
    return method_or_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/jython/Lib/_socket.py", line 357, in handle_exception
    return method_or_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/jython/Lib/ssl.py", line 287, in wrap_socket
    return SSLSocket(
  File "/jython/Lib/ssl.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/jython/Lib/ssl.py", line 165, in do_handshake
    raise SSLError(SSL_ERROR_SSL, e.strerror)
_socket.SSLError: [Errno 1] General SSLEngine problem (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem)
```

Same code works fine in python.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you or not specifying SSL certificate.
There are ways by which you can bypass certificate, look for them.  Look for following code in scala, I am doing same thing in scala. May help you.

> https://gist.github.com/junaidk/237e49c36b3752a29597

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue by following the post Trusting All Certificates In Jython (http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/)